# Disabling lock screen app in a Oukitel WP5 Pro afr

Tags: security

A friend just bought a Oukitel WP5 Pro powered by Android. It's up and running but he doesn't want the lock screen. In security it does not give the option "none". I went into app manager it doesn't so the app so i can't disable from there, I would really like some help. If I have to do a hard reset was should I do before I do it? I would like answers specifically for the Oukitel WP5 Pro. Thank you

Comment: Generally, there should be an equivalent of "swipe" when choosing the lock screen, but based on what I observe, it's not possible to remove the lock screen completely since it's baked into the Android system.

Comment: Do you get this message in your lock screen security settings: "disabled by administrator, encryption policy or credential storage"?

Comment: lock screen is dependency for encryption, therefore you can (maybe) set to *none* only if start from fresh factory reset (no specific WP5 answer just broad suggestion)